# mysqli_query is null but there are no error messages

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a sortable power ranking list for a madden nfl league. IF you want to see it its at

http://www.stephenjesse.com/projects/powerrankings/index.php

The problem I'm getting when I'm trying to calculate the change from the last saved ranking the query used to get the last ranking returns null sometimes causing the change to be wrong because it thinks the old rankings is 0 when its not. Here is a basic snippet of the for loop

```
foreach($order as $team)
{
    $query="SELECT * FROM powerrankings WHERE team='$team'";
    echo "query to select team:".$query."\n\n";
    $result=mysqli_query($db,$query) or die(mysqli_error($db));
    $selectedTeam=$result->fetch_assoc();
    $oldRank=intval($selectedTeam['ranking']);
    $change=$oldRank-$rank;
```

I'm not really sure what wrong, I check the apache error log, I've tried outputting mysqli_errer() and I've checked the mysql.log error log and nothing shows up.I've tried sleeping 5 seconds between queries incase the queries are being fired to quickly but that doesn't work. Its only some times. Here is a sample of the debug output I have on the page

query to select team:SELECT * FROM powerrankings WHERE team='Panthers'

team:Panthers
old rank:5
new rank:1

array(7) {
  ["ranking"]=>
  string(1) "5"
  ["team"]=>
  string(8) "Panthers"
  ["comment"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["change"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["record"]=>
  string(5) "0-0-0"
  ["low"]=>
  string(1) "5"
  ["high"]=>
  string(1) "5"
}
array dump:

query to select team:SELECT * FROM powerrankings WHERE team='Bills'

team:Bills
old rank:0
new rank:2

NULL
array dump:

query to select team:SELECT * FROM powerrankings WHERE team='Falcons'

team:Falcons
old rank:0
new rank:3

NULL
array dump:

query to select team:SELECT * FROM powerrankings WHERE team='Cardinals'

team:Cardinals
old rank:0
new rank:4

NULL
array dump:

query to select team:SELECT * FROM powerrankings WHERE team='Ravens'

team:Ravens
old rank:0
new rank:5

NULL
array dump:

query to select team:SELECT * FROM powerrankings WHERE team='Bears'

team:Bears
old rank:6
new rank:6

array(7) {
  ["ranking"]=>
  string(1) "6"
  ["team"]=>
  string(5) "Bears"
  ["comment"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["change"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["record"]=>
  string(5) "0-0-0"
  ["low"]=>
  string(1) "6"
  ["high"]=>
  string(1) "6"
}

a you can see sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` means that there are no matching rows for you query: no team named "Bills".

Do a check in your code for `NULL` before updating ranking

```
if ($selected_team = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // update ranking
}
```

Comment: Update sorry there is a team named bills, if I do it again I get something like this query to select team:SELECT * FROM powerrankings WHERE team='Bills'

team:Bills
old rank:2
new rank:1

array(7) {
  ["ranking"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["team"]=>
  string(5) "Bills"
  ["comment"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["change"]=>
  string(2) "-2"
  ["record"]=>
  string(5) "0-0-0"
  ["low"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["high"]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
array dump:

query to select team:SELECT * FROM powerrankings WHERE team='Ravens'

team:Ravens
old rank:0
new rank:2

NULL
array dump:

Comment: I should be checking for NULL though, and exiting I think. It seems to happen to the ones in the list I don't move usually. Thats why I'm wondering if there is something possible blocking there query, but I can't find any information to see if thats the case.